render properties panel lack of ambivient occlusion and others
I tried to adjust my 3D model to make it more realistic, so I looked for ambient occlusion in the render properties panel but couldn't find it.
please can you help find the solution?
my regards.

Ambient occlusion is a side-effect of raytracing, you don't have directly a setting about it. The number of bounces of light rays influcences the ambient occlusion. There is also an node called Ambient Occlusion in the shader editor that you can use.
